# Not found vs Method not allowed when deleting resource via Restful service

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm new to writing restful web services and I have a question regarding the correct use of the response codes 404 (Not found) and 405 (Method not allowed).

When consuming a web service URL `systemuser/delete/[user-id-here]`, if the user has already been deleted (and therefore does not exist) I am under the impression I should be returning the `404 Not Found` status code as the resource no longer exists? Or should I return the `405 Method not allowed` as the address is valid, but the resource is no longer available to delete and therefore the action cannot be carried out?

Many thanks

Comment: I'd do 404 in this case, 405 if the resource is found but deletion is not possible. That said REST isn't a hard and fast specification and I doubt any client will distinguish between `4xx` response codes at all.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I do in fact have an instance where the resource is found but cannot be deleted.

Comment: I would suggest you to please read HTTP specifications for error codes 404 and 405, it would be more clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly Resource Not Found - `404 error response`. When you make a request like `DELETE+/user/{id} -` If the Id is not present - `throw HTTP 404 (also read HTTP specs)`
and if the delete operation is not specified for this resource ,then the response will be `405` , i.e method not allowed.

One more suggestion - do not add the verbs into the URLs , like instead `/user/delete/{id} just make it /user/{id} + HTTP DELETE.`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I have been reading the HTTP specifications, I'm just getting confused between contexts (the method existing at that location vs the resource being available). Certainly reversing the URL as you suggest helps clear this up as the URL /user/{id} would return a 404 regardless.